# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - while doing feature engineering

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run the code below

```
# Creation of X1_new
X1_new = []
for x in X1:
    torque = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2
    sqr = torque ** 0.5
    X1_new.append(x + [sqr])
print(X1_new[0]) # Look at the first input
```

My first input should look like this: X1_new[0] = [-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0, 61.0163912403872]

But I am getting this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"
below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b7c1aa5c3c02> in <module>
      3 X1_new = []
      4 for x in X1:
----> 5     torque = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2
      6     sqr = torque ** 0.5
      7     X1_new.append(x + [sqr])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: If `X1` is a list of numbers, and `x` is iterating through `X1`, then `x` is a number. So what is `x[0]` supposed to be?

Comment: x[0] picks the first number in X1

Comment: What is `X1` to begin with? Your code assumes it looks something like `[[1,2,3], ...]`, not `[1, 2, 3, ...]`.

Comment: X1 is [-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0]. The last value to be added is the sum of squares of the first 3 numbers. The error is pointed at the torque calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscribable` because you are trying to assign a value to the first element in a list that doesn't have elements in it. 
you can try

```
X1_new = []
X1_new.append([-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0, 61.0163912403872])
```

and tha will create you the desire element in the first place of the list in index [0]. 
Or you can initate the list with an element like

```
X1_new = [[]]
```

and then you will be able to do

```
X1_new[0] = [-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0, 61.0163912403872]
```

Comment: I have tried it but I have thesame error. The error keeps pointing at the line "torque ="

Comment: Probably the X1 list is empty try to do my answer to X1.

Comment: X1 is [-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0]. The last value to be added is the sum of squares of the first 3 numbers. The error is pointed at the torque calculation.

Comment: So if you are doing `for x in [-1, -1, 61, -3, 0, 0, 61.0163912403872]:` and then `torque = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2` you will get error because the x is not a list.

Comment: Just checked the type(X1) and it came back as a list.

Comment: That is right but when you are iterate over it you are iterating on int's so you can do indexing to the int elements. `for x in X1` the x is int so you can't x[0], x[1], x[2].

Comment: Quite clear now. I tried `X1_new = [[ ]]` but still have the error.

Comment: I created X1 as a dataframe to view it after generating X1 and that was what caused the error. Thanks for your time@Leo Arad